# Jquery - How can I update a div with new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a graph in my webpage and whenever I click a point in my graph, I want a div to be updated with new content. Through my function, I managed to update it, but when I click on a new point, new content is added to the old one and so on, given that I want to have only the current content in my div.

Here's my function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(div_to_update).text(content);
});
```

}

I tried to implement

```
$("#chart_div").click(function()
   $('#div_to_update').remove();
});
```

but obviously it removes my div and I'm unable to recover it then.

Comment: What is `$(document).ready` doing there? Also, the first function should replace the content of `#id`, so maybe the id you pass is wrong?

Comment: First you say you add things, than you say you want to remove, than you say you're unable to recover things... c'mon make up your mind, edit your question into something understandable. Perhaps a demo, to see what you want, would just be of help.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I think I made myself clear. I said what it happens: "when I click on a new point, new content is added to the old one and so on" and what I expect to happen: " given that I want to have only the current content in my div.". Then I said that "remove()" obviously removes the DIV and ofc I DON't have that div anymore there to update. I can't figure out why you have to be so sharp ...

Comment: @AlexThomason my apologies if it sounded *sharp*! It was hard to understand what was going to be kept removed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I my opinion, if you want to change data in a div when something is clicked,
you could do it this way:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".point").click(function() {
      var content = $(this).attr('value');
      $("#div-to-update").html(content);
   });
});
</script>
```

in the body of your page...

```
<div id='graph'>
   <div class='point' value='10'>
   <div class='point' value='100'>
   <div class='point' value='1000'>
</div>

<div id='div-to-update'>
    // when point is clicked, content here will change
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM use `empty()`

```
$("#chart_div").click(function(){
    $("#div_to_update").empty();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want remove inside of your div use this function

```
$("#div_to_update").empty();
```

also **.text(content)**  only sets the content as text, not html. 
If you want to set it as html use **.html()** function like this

```
$("#div_to_update").html(content);
```